# Kubuntu loading screen in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, kubuntu

Long ago I was impressed with KDE4 screenshots and installed kubuntu-desktop on my Ubuntu. After a while I was tired of it, it's just too overloaded and Ctrl+Alt+Scroll doesn't work so I removed it. But loading screen still saying "Kubuntu" even after Ubuntu upgrade this spring. How can I get original loading screen back?

Comment: I have a similar case; but never bothered to change it. What diff does it make any way. Also, in general, g33ks use KDE often than gnome ;)

Comment: It didn't bother me as well but I thought I can ask anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-artwork-usplash kubuntu-default-settings
```